# Firefox plugin autoupdate does not work even with mccoy sign and sha1 hash

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm new here. I attempted to follow the basic guide to setting up my plugin to autoupdate, but no matter what I tried, the Addons Manager simply returns "No updates found" to me.

This is my first version, with the McCoy updateKey and the updateURL.

```js
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
 <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
  <em:id>rikaicake@kirei.cake</em:id>
  <em:name>RikaiCake Custom JP-EN Dictionary</em:name>
  <em:version>1.0.20141010</em:version>
  <em:description>The next generation Rikaichan dictionary, catered for translators and dedicated Japanese enthusiasts alike, by one single wholehearted translator. (Disclaimer: No credit is claimed for the creation of the original dictionary by James Breen or any others involved. This is solely a fan contribution.)</em:description>
  <em:creator>Nitori</em:creator>
  <em:homepageURL>http://kireicake.com/rikaicakehome/</em:homepageURL>
  <em:iconURL>chrome://rikaicake/content/icon.png</em:iconURL>
  <em:icon64URL>chrome://rikaicake/content/icon64.png</em:icon64URL>
  <em:unpack>true</em:unpack>
  <em:type>2</em:type>

  <!-- Update variables -->
  <em:updateURL>http://kireicake.com/rikaicake/update.rdf</em:updateURL>
  <em:updateKey>MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDLELaF2leBsPJJXGwEW8Eju5crK/vXDHmNFbNb7I/na64jX00tNud8sjjRQiXmkm7rRqdmIkwqsvCJAeF92HmLRAN9DxxLHUcNO5TJ9MpsjgnJnS9Cpwp+9iQHzG5JE8IhyeuqL9UH1l8840q+o1F5+aU0gQfCXVq7ml35Cp5AcwIDAQAB</em:updateKey>

  <!-- Firefox -->
  <em:targetApplication>
                           ...
  </em:targetApplication>
  
 </Description>
</RDF>
```

Next is the update.rdf, which contains both the McCoy signature as well as the correct sha1 hash of the new version's XPI file.

```js
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF:RDF xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#"
         xmlns:NC="http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#"
         xmlns:RDF="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <RDF:Seq RDF:about="rdf:#$juwpx">
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="rdf:#$kuwpx"/>
  </RDF:Seq>
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="rdf:#$nuwpx"
                   em:id="rikaicake@kirei.cake"
                   em:minVersion="2.0"
                   em:maxVersion="99.*"
                   em:updateLink="http://kireicake.com/rikaicake/rikaicake-1.1.20141011.xpi"
                   em:updateHash="sha1:a88f474ce465ec8b027bf9d59f26aa4d758c1b0d" />
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mozilla:extension:rikaicake@kirei.cake"
                   em:signature="MIGTMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBDQUAA4GBAICj86yogJPhb4PKRfcXnqd2rGRVoo89TULFi6urSODlVW97RjwVkUt9t4cgvGvk8g5Ix8xVNKlybBLkXOfzMIIbWWMrK9MUHHly1Pi2BdW2ecOoUOEPpB73hVLwJggrVLCFogFoATtVLBMHC6wjxvRGfLt2M5alUu1jpm3RxOCF">
    <em:updates RDF:resource="rdf:#$juwpx"/>
  </RDF:Description>
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="rdf:#$kuwpx"
                   em:version="1.1.20141011">
    <em:targetApplication RDF:resource="rdf:#$nuwpx"/>
  </RDF:Description>
</RDF:RDF>
```

And, just for reference, the updated install.rdf in the new version is basically the exact same albeit with a different em:version number (newer one).

```js
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
 <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
  <em:id>rikaicake@kirei.cake</em:id>
  <em:name>RikaiCake Custom JP-EN Dictionary</em:name>
  <em:version>1.1.20141011</em:version>
  <em:description>The next generation Rikaichan dictionary, catered for translators and dedicated Japanese enthusiasts alike, by one single wholehearted translator. (Disclaimer: No credit is claimed for the creation of the original dictionary by James Breen or any others involved. This is solely a fan contribution.)</em:description>
  <em:creator>Nitori</em:creator>
  <em:homepageURL>http://kireicake.com/rikaicakehome/</em:homepageURL>
  <em:iconURL>chrome://rikaicake/content/icon.png</em:iconURL>
  <em:icon64URL>chrome://rikaicake/content/icon64.png</em:icon64URL>
  <em:unpack>true</em:unpack>
  <em:type>2</em:type>

  <!-- Update variables -->
  <em:updateURL>http://kireicake.com/rikaicake/update.rdf</em:updateURL>
  <em:updateKey>MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDLELaF2leBsPJJXGwEW8Eju5crK/vXDHmNFbNb7I/na64jX00tNud8sjjRQiXmkm7rRqdmIkwqsvCJAeF92HmLRAN9DxxLHUcNO5TJ9MpsjgnJnS9Cpwp+9iQHzG5JE8IhyeuqL9UH1l8840q+o1F5+aU0gQfCXVq7ml35Cp5AcwIDAQAB</em:updateKey>

  <!-- Firefox -->
  <em:targetApplication>
                            ...
  </em:targetApplication>
  
 </Description>
</RDF>
```

I've also set up my .htaccess so that it would properly handle the files.

```js
AddType text/rdf .rdf
AddType text/xml .rdf
AddType application/rdf+xml .rdf
AddType application/x-xpinstall .xpi
```

Does anybody have any idea what I could be doing wrong? I don't own my server, so I cannot set it to do HTTPS, so that is not an option. I tried several Firefox browsers, and they all do the same. The files can be accessed on the website, no problem at all.

For one thing, is my code wrong by any chance? If not, then I might just need to tell people to manually update. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found out the issue. It's working now. The issue was in my **update.rdf**:

```js
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF:RDF xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#"
         xmlns:NC="http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#"
         xmlns:RDF="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="rdf:#$nuwpx"
                   em:id="{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}"
                   em:minVersion="2.0"
                   em:maxVersion="99.*"
                   em:updateLink="http://kireicake.com/rikaicake/rikaicake-1.1.20141011.xpi"
                   em:updateHash="sha1:a88f474ce465ec8b027bf9d59f26aa4d758c1b0d" />
  <RDF:Seq RDF:about="rdf:#$juwpx">
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="rdf:#$kuwpx"/>
  </RDF:Seq>
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mozilla:extension:rikaicake@kirei.cake"
                   em:signature="MIGTMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBDQUAA4GBABuMUOfHzXvWVu2LlIxZalk94+HFLShDfugBBH7uUEU1knq7imKBIQ8Ilw38lJ/hfxVpXQx8jxywGBx6QPeqFMmBhu9ocKTiWIUQ+52O2i2p1pCw0VrcEd90KP1Tj0IXXthIpILp/VQMif4cloOaI//4ql27xHe0+L/NXkB/JZbN">
    <em:updates RDF:resource="rdf:#$juwpx"/>
  </RDF:Description>
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="rdf:#$kuwpx"
                   em:version="1.1.20141011">
    <em:targetApplication RDF:resource="rdf:#$nuwpx"/>
  </RDF:Description>
</RDF:RDF>
```

**em:id should be {Firefox GUID}, NOT the addon's ID.** I went through a ton of trouble just to realize that I misinterpreted a field.